# como faço para excluir uma categoria do wordpress dos resultados do google?

Tags: wordpress

Tenho um site em wordpress com algumas categorias por exemplo "nossos-clientes", "portfolio", "artigos" mas a categoria nossos clientes não deve aparecer nos resultados do Google se alguém poder ajudar agradeço

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=pt-BR

Answer (score 1):

Outra opção e acredito que seja mais simples, é adicionar um arquivo chamado robots.txt na raiz do site.

Dentro deste arquivo coloque:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /nossos-clientes
```

Isto diz para todos os robôs para não indexarem o link nossos-clientes e tudo abaixo dele. Você pode especificar um único link se precisar, colocando toda a url, exemplo:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /nossos-clientes/meu-cliente
```

No caso acima, apenas o "meu-cliente" não seria indexado e o link "nossos-clientes" sim.

> Recomendado para sites em WordPress:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/

# Seus bloqueios personalizados #
Disallow: /nossos-clientes
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usar o plugin Yoast e aplicar o código e remover apenas a categoria na mão:

1. Instale o plugin: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/
2. Adicione o código em seu functions.php:

`function sitemap_exclude_taxonomy( $value, $taxonomy ) {
if ( $taxonomy == 'nossos-clientes') return true;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 'sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 10, 2 );`